# Lexplore and split windows

Tags: vim-windows, netrw

Like many, I like to browse using `:Lexplore`. However, as indicated by the manual,

> By default, :Lexplore will change an uninitialized |g:netrw_chgwin|                                                                                                                                                                          to 2; edits will thus preferentially be made in window#2.

Additionally, I have set

```
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
```

to open the files from the explorer in the previous buffer.

Now, if I have only a single window opened, it works fine. But consider the following sequence

```
:edit foo.txt
:split bar.txt
:2wincmd w
```

We have bar.txt open on the top, foo.txt on the bottom and currently active.

Now, if I call `:Lexplore` it will set the `g:netrw_chgwin` to 2 as indicated in the help. So opening a file in the explorer will take place in the bar.txt's window.

Furthermore, the help for `g:netrw_browse_split` states that

> This option does not affect |:Lexplore| windows.

I can try to set `g:netrw_chgwin` as

```
:let g:netrw_chgwin = winnr()
:Lexplore
```

But on foo.txt, it gets the number 2 (2/2). After opening the explorer, foo.txt's windows gets assigned the number 3 (explorer taking the 1). So opening will again use bar.txt's window.

I tried to use

```
:let l:cur_buf = bufnr('%');
:Lexplore
:let g:netrw_chgwin = bufwinnr(l:cur_buf)
```

But to no avail.

**How can I override `:Lexplore`'s default behaviour? Or make it to open on the last visited window?**

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. I’ll leave it to someone else to fix your splitting issue; in the meantime, I’ll suggest an alternative workflow (one that works well for me). It consists of two steps:

1. `Explore`
2. `<CR>`

That’s it.

The idea is to let netrw take over the window I’m editing in, and open my next file directly in that window (not split it). This way, I don’t have to guess where my new file will go on the screen.

Additionally, `:Rexplore` is handy to switch between netrw and a file. And mapping a sequence of keys (like `<Leader>ed`) to `Explore` makes this really quite quick.

See also [project drawers and file explorers](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/)